# Control a webpage trough python or any other programming language

Tags: android, python, webview

I want to build a videomapping which you control with an Android device.

Say, I have a webpage that is totally black, and then on the Android device, I have a WebView app which has a few buttons. Every time I click on one of those buttons, that should trigger an event in the webpage, like showing some shapes or switch colors.

I know how to write an Android app with python sl4a alongside with HTML, CSS and JS. My question is, how can I broadcast these events to a webpage, making it trigger those effects when I click on a button on the Android side, using Python or another language.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can *not* trigger an event directly in a web page from any android app. What you can do, however, is from the android app store the changes into some backend storage (or server). Then the webpage can have a auto refresh, and see changes related to the backend storage (or server).

Another version of getting this kind of communication is to set up message queues. Then you would setup that the android app is pushing messages, and the webpages sets up a listener and reads messages from the queue. It can then react to the messages.

Unfortunately, I don't currently now what kind of message queues are available for android, python, ..., so you have to do a little research there. You also need to know if that message queue is somehow supported by your webpage, either in javascript or some serverside scripting of that webpage.

Hope this is enough information to get you going!